# Foundation Framework Screen Compatibility Issues

Tags: css, frameworks, screen, compatibility

I used the Zurb Foundation Framework to create a website on an HP Envy X2 PC Laptop with a 1366 x 768 32 bit screen resolution. My code works fine when opened on computers with larger screens, but when I tried my website on a smaller netbook screen, the main content (excluding the banner and footer) became squished. By squished, I mean that instead of the content spanning the screen in 3 neat columns, the words and images were set in a vertical display with each  being put underneath the one before it.

I was under the impression that the Zurb Foundation Framework is designed to work on all devices, big and small. I am mistaken?

I didn't touch the CSS aside from changing my html {background-image} and a:hover {color} so I'm curious as to how it would fail on smaller screen resolutions.

I tried the Zurb Foundation Forums, but that place dead, just filled with questions that float around never to be answered.

If anyone knows why I could be experiencing smaller screen problems, I would appreciate any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ***problems*** you are experiencing are by design. Looking at the docs for [Foundation Grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html#small-grid) we see that there are classes that tell the grid how to respond to certain screen sizes `.small-*, .medium-*, .large-*` (where `*` is the number of cells the element should span).

Following this convention, if we wanted 3 columns on a large and small screen we would need the markup to look as follows:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="columns small-4 large-4 panel">
        <h3>One</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="columns small-4 large-4 panel">
        <h3>Two</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="columns small-4 large-4 panel">
        <h3>Three</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

specifying the class `small-*` makes sure the column will adhere to the specified size when the screen is "small".

In short, make sure you add the class `.small-*` to your columns  if you want them to adhere to a specific width on smaller screen sizes.

**Edit**

Here is a snippet showing the differences

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Foundation Grid</title>
  <link href="http://cdn.foundation5.zurb.com/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Without ".small-"</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="columns large-4 panel">
      <h3>One</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="columns large-4 panel">
      <h3>Two</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="columns large-4 panel">
      <h3>Three</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1>With ".small-"</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="columns small-4 large-4 panel">
      <h3>One</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="columns small-4 large-4 panel">
      <h3>Two</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="columns small-4 large-4 panel">
      <h3>Three</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```